# single sign on (SSO) for a web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, single-sign-on

Our application is developed using asp.net and vb.net. It is a SAAS based application and is hosted with Rackspace

We need to implement Single sign on for our SAAS application, so that users of the application, users who will belong other corporate domains e.g  domain1\abc.user and domain2\xyz.user can login automatically as long as they are logged on to their domain, as per above example user abc.user shall be automatically logged into to our application as long as he is logged into domain1.

Can you pl let me know it can be implemented

Comment: Could you explain what does SAAS stand for? We are using Oracle Single Sign On service here in our company. I am not sure if it can be configured to automatically sign in people from other domains, but it requires the user to log in once, and it will do the job every other time.

Comment: By SAAS i mean "Software as a service" or cloud based application e.g. http://www.freshbooks.com/ is a SAAS application

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk Server uses Enterprise SSO which I have used in the past; there's no need to install (or buy, eeeek) BizTalk to use this: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx

Hope that helps